# Blur behind drawer in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm looking for a way to make the whole application behind a drawer get blurred, not just an activity, but anywhere you open the drawer.

Comment: Hi, welcome. As in the case of many programming things, there might be many ways to achieve the same thing, depending in the context. That being said, please show us what you have tried to do to solve the issue. At minimal, show us the code that you have tried to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a little hack that requires editing the flutter source files (in Android Studio, press CTRL + B while `Drawer` is selected to go to its source file):

In drawer.dart, add a new import:

```
import 'dart:ui' show ImageFilter;
```

And replace code near line 400:

```
child: new Container(
  color: _color.evaluate(_controller),
)
```

with:

```
child: new BackdropFilter(
  filter: new ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10.0 * _controller.value, sigmaY: 10.0 * _controller.value),
  child: Container(color: Color(0x01000000)),
),
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I tried using Stack -> [BackDropFilter -> SizedBox.expand(), Drawer] which actually worked wonders as I didn't want to change any source files in the drawer component.

So my code now looks something like this :

```
Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
  drawer: SafeArea(
    child: Stack(
      children: [
        BackdropFilter(
          filter: ImageFilter.blur(
            sigmaX: 5.0,
            sigmaY: 5.0,
          ),
          child: const SizedBox.expand(),
        ),
        Drawer(
          child: ...
```

The backdrop is still tappable and it works just like how the accepted answer seems to work.

[a sample drawer with blurred backdrop screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXGgl.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

If you want to achieve something like this that the background of `Drawer` itself should be blur then this code will help you out

```
Drawer(
    backgroundColor: Colors.black87.withOpacity(0.6),
    child: ClipRRect(
      child: BackdropFilter(
        filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5.0, sigmaY: 5.0),
        child: ...,
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put your drawers's child to BackDropFilter widget.

```
Scaffold(
          drawer: Drawer(
            child: BackdropFilter(
              filter: ImageFilter.blur(
                sigmaX: 5.0,
                sigmaY: 5.0,
              ),
              child: YourDrawerChild()
```

Comment: This solution only works somewhat... It also blurs a decent part of the drawer... it's not nice

Answer (score 0):

The drawer prop in the Scaffold widget is of type Widget, wrap your Drawer widget with the BackdropFilter widget:

```
return WillPopScope(
  onWillPop:  () async => false,
  child: Scaffold(
    body: const Text('This is body'),
    drawer: BackdropFilter(
        filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 1, sigmaY: 1),
        child: const Drawer(
          child: Text('This is drawer.'),
        ),
    ),
  ),
);
```